# How to use GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

How do I use GNU parallel with aws sync command?

I have a file with the following commands:

```
aws s3 cp ./test s3://test --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.html" --profile $PROFILE

aws s3 cp ./test s3://test  $S3BUCKET --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.css" --profile $PROFILE
```

How can I use GNU parallel to run these commands in parallel?

What I did was add the commands in a file called test.sh

and I run the following command

```
parallel < test.sh
```

]
How do I pass in arguments to the test.sh file? For example, I want to pass in the aws bucket name.

Comment: If you just want to run a few commands in parallel, use `&` instead of GNU parallel.

Comment: that runs it in the background. I need GNU parallel so that if one command fails, the whole thing fails

Comment: You mean you want the behavior of `--halt 2`?

Comment: What does halt --2 do?

Comment: `--halt 2` is the GNU parallel option that kills all jobs if one fails. `--halt 1` just doesn't execute any more jobs, which is what `&` would accomplish.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. How can I use GNu parallel to run the commands above?

Comment: You realize you can use `&`, **and** make your script fail if either command does? Easily, even.

Comment: ...which is to say: You don't need GNU parallel for this; it's a massive ball of complexity (take a quick glance at the source if you doubt this!), and adds no value for your immediate use case.

Comment: (also, what do you mean "plugin"? Parallel isn't a bash plugin; there *is* support for C extensions to the shell that add new builtins, but there are very very few of them).

Comment: To be clear as to why you're getting answers that don't address your literal question: Think about the response you'd expect if someone asked in Woodworking SE about how to drive screws with a hammer.

Comment: ...as for answering the question of how to pass arguments, doesn't the answer by @thatotherguy address it adequately?

Comment: If you don't like needing to use `export`, you could just do the following (all on one line): `S3BUCKET=foo MAXAGE=42 PROFILE=bar parallel --gnu <test.sh`.

Comment: It sounds as if you have more than 2 commands. Maybe you really have 18? If so: Please show the 18 commands. It will make it much easier to give you the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to trigger a script failure if any member of a set of hand-written commands fails, GNU parallel isn't the best tool for the job: The shell itself already provides everything needed with the `wait` command, [which is specified by POSIX and present out-of-the-box on all standards-compliant shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wait.html) (see also the specification [requiring it to be implemented as a builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01_01)).

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- Important! /bin/sh doesn't have arrays; bash, ksh, or zsh will work.

# For readability, put common arguments in an array
common_args=(
  --recursive
  --content-encoding "gzip"
  --content-type "text/html"
  --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE"
  --exclude "*"
  --profile "$PROFILE"
)

# Record PIDs of the various jobs in an array
pids=( )
aws s3 cp ./test s3://test             --include='*.html' "${common_args[@]}" & pids+=( $! )
aws s3 cp ./test s3://test "$S3BUCKET" --include='*.css'  "${common_args[@]}" & pids+=( $! )

# If either background job failed, exit the script with the same exit status
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  wait "$pid" || exit
done
```

Note that arrays are used above for convenience, not necessity; you could provide the common arguments with a function, and/or build up the array of PIDs in a scalar variable or by overriding "$@" inside a shell function if your goal were to write code that would work on any POSIX baseline shell.

Comment: I have about 10+ of this aws commands to run. I need them to run at the same time

Comment: The above *does* run the `aws s3 cp` commands at the same time. If you want an actual proper loop to start these jobs, that'd be easy too, but your question doesn't give much to go on re: tuning the answer beyond what I've already done.

Comment: (Are you, for instance, trying to iterate over pairs of S3BUCKET and PROFILE values?)

Comment: No I have 18 aws sync commands. They don't all have the same S3bucket. 6 of them have the same S3 bucket

Comment: ...so, if you wanted to use the answer here, you could copy the pattern, with `aws s3 ... & pids+=( $! )` for each command you want to run, and the `wait` loop to check exit status after and exit with an error if any failed.

Comment: How do we exit 1 if there is an error with one of the commands?

Comment: @JamesUmeris, `wait "$pid" || exit` exits with the same exit status the backgrounded `aws` command whose pid is being processed, should that value be nonzero. (I thought I was clear about this on the comments to the script as originally posted). If you want to `exit 1` instead of copying the exit status of the failed command through, that would be `wait "$pid" || exit 1` instead.

Comment: so just so that I understand if a command fails, the code that you wrote as it is  `(wait "$pid" || exit)` will exit with a 1 (for failure).

Comment: You don't want the parenthesis -- they'll break it. And as I said, several times, it exits *with the same status of the command that failed*, which may or may not be 1.

Comment: ...so, if rsync exits with status 8, then `wait "$pid" || exit` when given the PID of that rsync will exit your script with status 8. Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
export MAXAGE
export PROFILE
export S3BUCKET

part1() {
  aws s3 cp ./"$1" s3://"$1" --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.html" --profile $PROFILE
}
export -f part1

part2() {
  aws s3 cp ./"$1" s3://"$1"  $S3BUCKET --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.css" --profile $PROFILE
}
export -f part2

parallel --halt 2 ::: part1 part2 ::: test testfile2
```

Use different $S3BUCKET:

```
doit() {
  file="$1"
  bucket=$2
  aws s3 cp ./"$file" s3://"$file"  $bucket --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.css" --profile $PROFILE
}
export -f doit

# '' = no bucket
parallel --halt 2 doit ::: test testfile2 ::: '' bucket1 bucket2 bucket3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by exporting all the required variables and then piping the commands to `parallel` with a quoted here-documented:

```
#!/bin/bash
export S3BUCKET="$1"
export MAXAGE=42
export PROFILE=foobar

parallel --gnu << 'EOF'
aws s3 cp ./test s3://test --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.html" --profile $PROFILE
aws s3 cp ./test s3://test  $S3BUCKET --recursive --content-encoding "gzip" --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=$MAXAGE" --exclude "*" --include "*.css" --profile $PROFILE
EOF
```